# Why Indian Government need permission from Bangladesh to visit Thailand through sea ways?

Tags: india

My General Knowledge professor told me, Indian Government need permission from Bangladesh to visit Thailand through **sea ways**.

Why they would need permission even Thailand is far away from Bangladesh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your professor may have been referring to [**BIMSTEC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bay_of_Bengal_Initiative_for_Multi-Sectoral_Technical_and_Economic_Cooperation), which is an agreement between the countries surrounding the Bay of Bengal to help improve things like trade. In this agreement, Bangladesh leads the Trade and Investment sector.